# How to push Splash Screen Loading View till its loaded

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have tried this for past few days and have not got any success yet. 
I am loading various XML Data once the application is launched. But currently I have not loaded any loading page to show the loading of the page. I would like to add a page which shows loading of my data and then push that loading view page to the tab bar controller page.
Does anyone have any example or any idea to share it, will be really helpful.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  (NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 
  [navController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; 
  LoadingViewController *lvc = [[LoadingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoadingView" bundle:nil]; 
  // Adding the modal view controller to loading View controller on Main Tab bar controller. Hope its correct
  [self.rootController presentModalViewController:lvc animated:YES]; 
  [window addSubview:rootController.view]; 
  [window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
 [self URL]; 
 [lvc release]; 
 return TRUE; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do something like this. One option is to create a viewcontroller that shows your loading view. add your tab bar controller to the window. Then present the loading view controller as a modal view controller over the tab bar controller. Then start your xml parsing, and dismiss the modal controller when the parsing is finished.

Comment: How should I add the loading view controller as a modal view controller on top of tab bar controller >? Do I need to use IB ?

Comment: UITabBarController is a subclass of UIViewController. All view controllers have a method called presentModalViewController: animated:  . Use that method to present the loading view controller. Do this in the app delegate.

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
 [navController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; 
 LoadingViewController *lvc = [[LoadingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoadingView" bundle:nil];
 [self.rootController presentModalViewController:lvc animated:YES];
 [window addSubview:rootController.view];
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];
 [self URL];
 [lvc release];
 return TRUE;
}
I have added the loading view controller as mentioned but now how to remove the loading view controller.

Comment: take a look at the documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Within the lvc-instance, simply call [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES] when done.

Comment: I want to impress that this is the correct way of doing it. For example keeping the splash view open without giving the user any information about what the app is doing shouldn't occur. Great comment.

Comment: Charlie: Should I add [window addSubview:loadingController.view] in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or how should I basically call loading view controller on my Tab bar application. Because the above code snippet wont call the loading view controller.

Comment: In didFinishLaunching, you should call presentModalViewController on the view controller whose view is assigned as the window's subview. The code you posted above looks correct, but it's very difficult to read. Could you post your code as an edit to your original question?

Comment: Sorry I added the code to your review instead of mine. I changed it to mine though.